My PHP Code works just when call in command line
I have a curl request with proxy
<?php
$botToken = "";
$chatId = "-1234";
$message = 'Test';
$data = [
    'chat_id' => $chatId,
    'text' => $message,
];
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot:token/sendMessage";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'example.proxy.com:1716');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '1716');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'passwd');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
    echo "No Error";
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>

and it will not connect while i run the code in browser :
Curl error: Failed to connect to example.proxy.com port 1716: Connection refused

but when i run from command line:
php aaa.php

it works without problem.
What is the problem?

You need to distinct between php-cli (command line) and php-fpm (called from webserver)

You say "it will not connect while i run the code in browser" but are you sure the code is being run? How have you set up your local web server to execute the PHP script? Or are you just loading an HTML page in the browser with the PHP embedded in it? We need more information about how it's all configured. At the moment your question is not about PHP but why a web server does not work.

i run  the code in a php file named aaa.php and it runs so i get the Connection refused error

Are you sure the code being run in the browser is the same as the code you are running on the command line? The error says "Failed to connect to example.proxy.com" - do you need to have a proxy configured? And if you do, I'm betting it shouldn't be "example.proxy.com"

@Tony I anonymized it, because of leaking credentials.

Ok, it would be useful to mention that sort of thing ;)

I flagged for deletion not to reveal. But the anonymization does not change anything. It's clearly a cli/fpm issue. Btw. you see it is edited :)

The problem solved by temporary allowing the ip:port in direct admin firewall
